# How to exclude directory structure in output with grunt-concat-json?

Tags: json, gruntjs, npm, assemble

I've been trying to get [grunt-concat-json](https://github.com/springroll/grunt-concat-json) to work with my directory structure. Currently, it looks like this:

```
_src/
  assembly/
    _data/**/*.json
```

The concat-json plugin has a feature that merges files into the same object if they share the same path. In other words, the output, given my directory structure, should be:

```
{
  "_src": {
    "assembly": {
      "_data": {
        "some_folder": {
          "some_keys": "some_values"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The plugin lets you set the current working directory, and makes sure that the working directory path isn't included in the output. So now my output should be:

```
{
  "some_folder": {
    "some_keys": "some_values"
  }
}
```

Yet, the output doesn't change when I set the current working directory. I don't believe I need "expand: true", otherwise it doesn't concatenate the files. At least, I haven't been able to get it to do so. Each source file is simply copied into the destination folder with expand set to true.

My concat-json grunt task:

```
"concat-json": {
    options: {
        space: '\t',
    },
    "pre_assemble": {
        cwd: '<%= pkg.buildPath %>assembly/_data/',
        src: '**/*.{json,yml}',
        dest:'<%= pkg.buildPath %>assembly/_data/casestudy.json'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I only needed to get rid of the trailing slash in the cwd setting.

```
"concat-json": {
    options: {
        space: '\t',
    },
    "pre_assemble": {
        cwd: '<%= pkg.buildPath %>assembly/_data',
        src: '**/*.{json,yml}',
        dest:'<%= pkg.buildPath %>assembly/_data/casestudy.json'
    }
}
```

Correctly excludes all the folders in the working directory from the output.